# Renaming Multiple sub folders in windows powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, rename

Is there anyway to rename multiple folders for example below

Old

```
aaa 15111
aaa 15123
aaa 15125
```

New

```
aaa_15111
aaa_15123
aaa_15125
```

I can do this quite easily for files but does not work with folders

```
get-childitem *.* | foreach {rename-item $_ $_.name.replace("REPLACE THIS TEXT","WITH THIS TEXT")}
```

Comment: what is the issue? why does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can find folders having a space using `Get-ChildItem -Filter '* *' -Directory` and you can replace 1 or more spaces with an underscore with `-replace '\s+', '_'` putting both things together:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter '* *' -Directory |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\s+', '_' }
```

Comment: thanks that works, i just have a liitle additional, say it wasn't a space and it was a string like the word 'and' how would i do that?

Comment: change `\s+` for `and` @SamuelGidman